# Assign Session Values Via Object

Tags: php, oop, session

I have been trying to assign/change/update session values within an object.

What i am trying to do is to create a session and assign a value in object format and update its values where the object is called/initiated.

```
<?php
    class Session {
        var $namespace; //NULL by Default
    var $session;
    //run session essantials
    public function __construct($SessionName=null, $assignedValue=null, $boolenerOfType=NULL){
        $this->namespace = (!empty($SessionName))?$SessionName:NULL;
            if(!empty($_SESSION[$SessionName])){
            if(!empty($assignedValue)){
                    //this overwrites the existing value of the session
                        $_SESSION[$SessionName] = $assignedValue? $assignedValue : new stdClass;

                    }else{//end of if
                        $_SESSION[$SessionName] = (!empty($_SESSION[$SessionName])==true)? $_SESSION[$SessionName] : new stdClass;
                    }

            }elseif(!isset($_SESSION[$SessionName]) or empty($_SESSION[$SessionName])){//end of if

                    //$_SESSION[$SessionName] = ($assignedValue==NULL)? (new stdClass): function($assignedValue){   foreach($assignedValue as $val){}};
                    $_SESSION[$SessionName]== new stdClass;
            }//end of else of if

        $this->session = $_SESSION[$SessionName];



        foreach($this->session as $num=>$val){
            $this->$num=$val;
        }

        foreach($_SESSION[$SessionName] as $num=>$val){
            $this->$num=$val;
        }
        //debug::dump($this);
        unset($this->session);

        return $this;   

    }//end of function



    static public function unsetSession($sessionName){
        unset($_SESSION[$sessionName]);
        return true;
    }//end of function
    public function setSessionValue($valueObject, $obj){
        $SessionName = $obj->namespace;
        $_SESSION[$SessionName]=$valueObject;
    }//end of function


    public function __destruct(){
        //$reassignSession = $this->session;
        $this->__construct($this->namespace);
        $SessionName = $this->namespace;
        //debug::dump($_SESSION);
        $methodsofClass = (get_class_methods ($this ));
        $valueObject = new stdClass;

        foreach($this as $id=> $value){
            if(!in_array($id, $methodsofClass) and $id!= 'namespace' and $id!= 'session'){
                $valueObject->$id=$value;
            }//end of if
        }//end of foreach
        foreach($_SESSION[$SessionName] as $num=>$val){
            $this->$num=$val;
        }
        $this->setSessionValue($valueObject, $this);

        return @$this->session;
    }//end of function
  }//end of class

        $session = new Session('somename');
        $session->var1 = 1;
        $session->var2 = 'some value';

        //and my session ends like this

        /*
         $_SESSION['somename'] = object(Session)#n {
          var1 => 1,
          var2=> 'some value'

          }



        */
         ?>
```

My code has Mistakes now because i have been trying things.
I am trying to create the logic.
How can i do this?
i tried using __desctruct() but i could not make it work.
    I have been trying so many things, i actually lost my path.
    Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't show enough detail about what you've tried or what you're trying to do. Please replace your `//my code here` sections with your code.

Comment: @scrowler i added the code but it is not functioning as expected.

Comment: do **not** store objects in $_SESSION, as objects that you need in 'bootstrap' code. It will end in tears. The issue is that all the class definitions must be in memory before they are used by 'session_start()'. Instead, ... hmm... You can do it but the 'bootstrap' sequence is rather fragile.

Comment: @RyanVincent i am aware of the risks. I am not storing any important data or crucial to the script. However this class will make a lot of things handy and will save time from repeating.

Comment: May i suggest you store the 'constructor array/id' of the object, in exactly the same manner of any other object, in the $_SESSION array. However, you may need to include the 'class' specifically at 'startup'. And then make it from the session information. It makes it really clear that 'the class' is needed to be included at startup.

Comment: @RyanVincent I was about to say the samething.